# Can a service principal Access admin Portal settings in PowerBi service?

Tags: powershell, powerbi, unauthorized, service-principal

**I cannot assign a capacity Id to a workspace via Powershell commands, logged in with a service principal.**

```
$workspace = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -name 'XXX-XX-XXXX-XXX'
$workspaceId = $workspace.Id
echo $workspaceId
Set-PowerBIWorkspace -Id $workspaceId -Scope "Organization" -CapacityId "XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX"
```

error message:

```
Set-PowerBIWorkspace: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

I have taken the following steps:
I have created a service principal and assigned it to a security group in Azure AD.
I Manually added this security group in the admin Portal in PowerBi service to allow service principals to interact with service (under developer settings).
**I have been able to (using PowerShell) login with the service principal and create a workspace.I can get all workspaces etc...**
**However, when I try to set a workspace capacity Id (assign it to a premium capacity) I get an unauthorized error.**
I suspect I cannot do this because to perform this action, I have to go under Admin Portal Settings > Workspaces (I need Admin Rights to PowerBi service), hence I'm trying to find a way to grant these admin permissions to the service principal.
Besides this, I have:

1. Assigned that same service principal in the security group to be
   workspace admin
2. Assign PowerBi administrator role in AAD to that service principal

But nothing worked.

Is there a way to perform these actions? Or is it a limitation of Service Principals?
Thank you,
Joao

Answer (score 0):

The admin APIs in general cannot be used when authenticating with service principal. Recently, they made it possible to use some of them, but not all. For example take a look at [Announcing new Admin APIs and Service Principal authentication to make for better tenant metadata scanning](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-my/blog/announcing-new-admin-apis-and-service-principal-authentication-to-make-for-better-tenant-metadata-scanning/) and [Enable service principal authentication for read-only admin APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/read-only-apis-service-principal-authentication), where you can see the list of [supported APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/read-only-apis-service-principal-authentication#supported-apis).

To assign a capacity to a workspace, [UpdateGroupsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-update-group-as-admin) API is used, which is currently not listed as a supported API, and is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-update-group-as-admin#permissions) only for "normal" authentication:

> **Permissions**
>
> The user must have administrator rights (such as Office 365 Global Administrator or Power BI Service Administrator).

while for other APIs ([GetGroupsAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-groups-as-admin#permissions), [PostWorkspaceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/workspace-info-post-workspace-info#permissions)) is explicitly documented that they can be used with a service principal:

> **Permissions**
>
> The user must have administrator rights (such as Microsoft 365 Global Administrator or Power BI Service Administrator) **or authenticate using a service principal.**

So either you have to wait for Microsoft to implement authentication with service principal (and there is no guarantee they will do that), or you will have to change the authentication (to use AAD account).

Comment: The issue with the aad user login is that using the same login code structure I cannot login as I get the following error message "(User and password authentication is not supported in .NET Core or with DeviceCode authentication.)" - Any idea how to fix this?